# uWSGI behind AWS application load balancer

Tags: django, uwsgi, amazon-elb

I'm having trouble getting an ALB -> uWSGI container setup working in AWS. I want to leave nginx out of the stack if possible.

Assume security groups aren't an issue - I have confirmed ELB can reach the containers on the dynamically-allocated host ports.

From [the uWSGI docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTP.html), --http is the way to go to make this work, but I must be missing something. Relevant ini:

```
[uwsgi]

socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
http-to = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
http = 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Is this correct? How should I configure uWSGI to receive http traffic from ALB?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Its actually `http-socket` that I needed. Uwsgi was indeed receiving traffic, but I was seeing this strange issue where the subdomain was being stripped off and the resulting site getting a 404.

For example, http://www.example.com was being immediately redirected to http://example.com and failing.

This was happening because of django, not uwsgi. Our [subdomain.middleware](https://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/middleware.html) was configured in such a way that a wildcard subdomain caused it to bail, and in doing so chop off that subdomain and redirect to http://example.com.

This was specific to our app, not uwsgi + django, but I thought I'd leave it here if it might move someone in the right direction.